# postion: sticky support removed from Firefox 31.0?

Tags: css, firefox, mozilla, sticky, browser-support

Very recently this used to work well in Firefox. Now, it seems to be broken. I can't find any relevant report on bugzilla or elsewhere... Anyone know what's up?

see caniuse:

http://caniuse.com/css-sticky

and then test in FF:

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html

Comment: As *Can I use* says, it’s behind a flag in `about:config`. If you were using the beta (or earlier) version of Firefox 31, it might have been enabled by default for testing.

Comment: It's odd because I was definitely using a typical non-beta version of Firefox. But oops -- I totally read caniuse incorrectly and assumed my version of FF was in the green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on @minitech's comment:

`position: sticky` is right now controlled by a preference, namely `layout.css.sticky.enabled`. You can turn it on in `about:config` if you'd like to play with it already in Firefox 31.

[Bug 916315](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=916315) enabled it by default starting with Firefox 32, which is currently in beta. It is supposed to be enabled by default when Firefox 32 becomes the stable release, however you never know what show-stopper bugs might be discovered in the beta period (or by Aurora and Nightly users).